# Changing Map parameters in Drools Flow

Tags: drools, jbpm

Am a beginner in drools flow and Jbpm 5.  I want to pass in some parameter in map and i need certain script tasks to alter that parameter. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

In an action script you can do something like:
kcontext.setVariable("name", value);

For example, if you have a variable i:
kcontext.setVariable("i", i + "Changed");

Note that you probably should define your variable as a process variable to be able to do this.  Click on the background of your process and in the Properties view, edit the "variables" property to add a new process property with a given name and type.

For more documentation, see:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.2/userguide/ch05.html#sec.data

Kris